# Handling mouse events on any FLTK Widget

Tags: user-interface, events, callback, fltk

It is very easy to handle event with FLTK Button (Fl_Button). This is done using callback() method inherited from Widget class. But I tried using with other widgets like Fl_Box (widget that displays image or text) but not worked and there is no compile error because Fl_Box is also subclass of Widget so something like `flbox_pointer->callback(mycallback)` is valid.

In Java you can use mouse event on any component like JButton, JPanel, JLabel etc, but in C++ FLTK seems very difficult.

So, somebody can help me with piece of code to do this. I have already checked their docs but all examples of callbacks deal with Fl_Button, not other Widgets. The method that looks like it works is `virtual int handle(int)` but it forces to create class, extending then overriding it (something that I don't like for now!).

Comment: Why would you want a callback on a label or a box?  It would imply that you are using a label or box as a button.  In that case you may as well design your code to use buttons instead of labels or boxes.  If you want a button with an image just use the image member of the button class.

Comment: Ok thank! It's perfect.